# Bypass basic authentication for referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication

I have made a terrible, terrible piece of htaccess code as a stop-gap to keep us going, but terrible code makes everyone unhappy. So here it is:

DomainA.com hosts some code we need to pull into DomainB.com and all subdomains of DomainB.com.

Here is the terrible code we came up with and slapped on DomainA.com's htaccess file that works:

```
<If "%{HTTP_REFERER} == 'https://DomainB.com/testpage1.php'">
</If>

<ElseIf "%{HTTP_REFERER} == 'https://DomainB.com/testpage2.php'">
</ElseIf>

<ElseIf "%{HTTP_REFERER} == 'https://DomainB.com/testpage3.php'">
</ElseIf>

<Else>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Our Walled Garden - Login Credentials Required"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Else>
```

Can you help us trim this down so that we don't have to define the protocol or specific subdomain for the request? I've messed around with some regex, I can't get even simple regex matches to work in the IF block.

Comment: Is that actually what your htaccess file looks like? What version of apache are you using?

Comment: Apache 2.4.10. The IF blocks are a new thing in 2.4 apparently. I'm not married to them, either. They just got the job done for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions, you could use `SetEnvIf` instead together with an addition `Require` clause.

Maybe something like:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ^https://DomainB\.com/(testpage1|testpage2|testpage3)\.php$ noauth=1

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Our Walled Garden - Login Credentials Required"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Require env noauth
```

When there are multiple `Require` directives, they are automatically grouped as "Require Any" (See [`Require` apache 2.4 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) ).

The Setenv directive matches against the referer, and if that matches the "noauth" env variable gets set. Then the require directives say either a valid-user or noauth env variable will satisfy the access.

Note that the referer can be easily forged, so this isn't exactly very secure.

Comment: I understand the referer may be forged, but this gate is a temporary measure that doesn't hide any really sensitive content. We don't want people looking at other parts of the site at this point in time.

Comment: I don't know why this one worked and everything I researched before didn't. Thank you sir.

Comment: @SageAMDP it may be because most of the other answers are for apache 2.2, the auth system got revamped in 2.4